# ng-click instead of submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms

After I click submit in a form, some javascript runs to modify the data and sends it to whatever the form action is specified in the HTML:

```
// Submit the form:
    // $form.get(0).submit();
    $('.submit', $(event.target.form)).click();
```

I would like to instead use ng-click and send that info to an angular function, such as vm.checkout().

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ngSubmit` directive instead of `ngClick` for form submit.It binds to the submit event which is fired when a `form` is submitted.

> ng-submit works only when forms submitted.
>   where as ng-click can work without form submit event.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.submitMe = function () {
    alert('Submitted');
  };
});

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form ng-submit="submitMe()" name="myForm">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

```
$scope.submit = function(data){
     // do something with data
}
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="temp.name" name="name"/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submit(temp)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a form you are submitting you should use [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit). Add the ng-submit tag with the corresponding function which will be in your controller. Then,  you will be able to handle the data from your form submission.

For example:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController"></form>
```

Comment: Ok, so how do I get a stripe payment form to send the token to my controller when it's done it's thing.  I can't make it work this way.

Comment: If you're sending something to a payment gateway, wouldn't you just submit it and wait for the promise to come back? Assuming that the return data includes the token.